# Displaying error while getting id from url

Tags: php, html, mysql

I got link in index.php page

```
<a href="info.php?id=1 ?>" class="cs-links">....</a>
```

there is database with user table (id is primary key)

this is my de.php page

```
<?php
require_once 'authController.php';(only for database connection)

$id = $_GET['id'];

$query = "SELECT title, type, image, sy, source
FROM   user
WHERE  user_id = $id";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query)) {

    /* execute statement */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $title, $type, $image, $sy $source);

    echo nl2br("$title /n$type /n$image /n$sy /n$source");

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

?>
```

It shows undefined variable &id when i execute above code in de.php what would be the problem can anyone help me with this

I have tried ansewrs from similar questions but nothing worked out the error still exists

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you really know about sql injection.
please use this code an make sure use the bind param

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user1", "datasoft123", "hr");
$id = 1;
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT SELECT title, type, image, sy, source WHERE user_id =?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* fetch value */
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if($result->num_rows === 0) exit('No rows');
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id[] = $row['title'];
        $name[] = $row['type'];
        $age[] = $row['image'];
    }
    $stmt->close();

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
```